# jQuery <li> and arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

We have list in html:

```
<ul class="list">
<li>some text<li>
<li>some text<li>
<li>some text<li>
<li>some text<li>
<li>some text<li>
...
<li>some text<li>
</ul>
```

There can be more than 100 `<li>`

**How to do:**

1) Add for each `<li>` id with number, like:

```
<li id="item1">some text<li>
<li id="item2">some text<li>
...
<li id="item200">some text<li>
```

and so on, to the end.

2) Count all `<li>` inside `<ul class="list">`

3) After second step, if there are more than 60 `<li>`, **add their IDs (item number)** to **array 1**, all other's `<li>` IDs add to **array 2** (from 60 to the end, from 60 to 500 if there are 500 `<li>`).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are WorkingHard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step 1:

```
var $li = $('ul.list > li').attr('id', function(i) { return "item" + (i + 1) });
```

Step 2:

```
var count = $li.length;
```

Step 3:

```
if(count > 60) {
    var arr1 = $li.slice(0,60);
    var arr2 = $li.slice(60);
}
```

**EDIT:** Mis-spelled `function`. Fixed.

**Note:** Of course, you don't need a `count` variable. `$li.length` can go inside the `if()` statement.

**Note:** The `.slice()` method will return a jQuery object. If you actually want an array, add `.get()` after `.slice()`. Or with jQuery 1.4 or later, you can use `.toArray()`.

Comment: nice, far more succinct than mine.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var items = $("ul.list").children(),
    size = items.size(),
    firstArray = [],
    secondArray = [];
items.each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 60) {
        firstArray.push(this);
    }
    else {
        secondArray.push(this);
    }
    index++;
    this.id = "item" + index;
});
```

Comment: what is ++index in this case?

Comment: this only the first step, what about second and third?

Comment: index of element inside node.

Comment: For #2, $('ul.list').length()

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.list').each(function() {
    var lis = $(this).find('li'),
        count = lis.length,
        first = [],
        second = [],
        overLimit = count > 60;

    lis.each(function(i,o){
        if ( i <60 ) {
           first.push(this)
        } else if ( (i > 60) && overLimit ) {
           second.push(this)
        }

        $(this).attr('id', 'item-' + i);
    })

});
```

Comment: @WorkingHard did you tried to do something before asking? Read API, googling?

Answer (score 2):

For second step:

```
$( "ul.li").length
```

And third:

```
var arr1 = $( "ul.li:lt(60)");
var arr2 = $( "ul.li:gt(60)");
```

I don't know what exactly do you mean by print but you can took an example from here:

```
$( arr2).each( function( item) { alert( item);});
```